# jQuery DIV overlapping background DIV

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've got a bit of a problem with my jQuery DIV.
I've got a DIV called 'allcontent' which holds all the HTML and inside that I have a 'headlinesarea' DIV that contains all the headlines for the website and a 'datacontentarea' DIV that contains all the fixtures/tables and etc on the right hand side and it is also a DIV that is floated to the right and is written before the 'headlinesarea' DIV as it has to float.

The 'allcontent' DIV contains a transparent back ground image with repeat-y so that when more content is added the image will continue to repeat downwards and that works fine with the 'headlinesarea DIV', but when I add a jQuery DIV that has league tables that can open up and collapse the 'allcontent' DIV won't stretch and the jQuery DIV ends up overlapping the 'allcontent' DIV's background image.

The link to my site is http://thefootballleague.clanteam.com/ and here you can see my collapsible jQuery DIVS that are Championship League, League 1 and League 2. When they are clicked they open fine but unfortunately they do not stretch the 'allcontent' DIV background.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the style:

```
#allcontent {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you iambriansreed, that has solved my problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: There are other methods but this works fine if you have a defined width, which you do.

Comment: This is NOT the proper solution to the problem...this will not clear the float: right which is applied to the datacontentarea div.

Comment: Does the fiddle not work for you @SoWeLie? If do what browser version. If it's < ie7 don't bother mentioning it.

Comment: It fixes the immediate issue, but it could cause side effects down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

at the bottom of **"allcontent"**

like this :

```
<div id="allcontent">

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="nav">
...
</div>
<div id="datacontentarea">
...
</div>
<div id="headlinesarea">
...
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>//add this
</div>
```

or make it

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

then add

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

on your stylesheet

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys but I have no sorted the problem, I appreciate your time and effort though.

Answer (score 0):

More appropriately, what you need is the clearfix:

http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Because your datacontentarea div is floating right, you will need to clear the float in order for the allcontent div to be sized properly.

Just apply the "clearfix" class to the "allcontent" div, after you've copied in the clearfix css of course.

This is the cleanest way to handle these types of floating issues.

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys but I have no sorted the problem, I appreciate your time and effort though.